Proving that the limit of $f(x,y) = \frac{\sin(x)y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is zero as $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$
I am just working on my calculus homework and the question asks for any $\epsilon > 0$ find some $\delta > 0$ such that  when $0 < |\vec{h}| < \delta$ there is $|f(\vec{h})| < \epsilon$. I am not sure if this is a correct choice of $\delta$ or if the approach makes any sense at all.
let $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, then when $x$ is close to zero we write $$f \le \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)r^3}{r^2} = r\cos(\theta)(1-\cos^2(\theta)) = r\cos(\theta) - r\cos^3(\theta) \le 2r < 2\delta < \epsilon,$$ so take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$

Use the inequalities
$$|\sin x|\leq|x|,\quad |xy|\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2},\quad \forall x,y\in\mathbb R。$$
For any given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=2\epsilon>0$,
when $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta $, we have
$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{|y|\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{|y|}{2}\leq\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}<\epsilon.$$
Hence
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x)y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0.$$

It is even simpler. We know:
$\forall x\in{\Bbb R},\left |\sin(x)\right |\le \left |x\right |$ and $
\forall (x, y)\in {\Bbb R}^2, x^2+y^2\ge y^2$.
So we immediately have:

if $y=0$, $f(x,y)=0$, so $\left|f(x,y)\right|<\epsilon$

if $y\ne 0$,
$\left|f(x,y)\right|\le\left|\frac{xy^2}{y^2}\right|\le \left|x\right| $
so: $\left|\vec h\right|<\epsilon\implies\left|x\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|f(x,y)\right|<\epsilon$


If we take $\delta = \epsilon$, we have
$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta>0, \left|\vec h\right|<\delta, \left|f(\vec h)\right|<\epsilon$ QED
